# what is the difference between concurrency thread group and ultimate thread group

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, threadgroup

[concurrency thread group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4l48.png)

[Ultimate thread group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQFTw.png)

Answer (score 0):

Both are pretty much similar when it comes to defining a load pattern when it comes to concurrency, however:

1. In the Ultimate Thread Group you can have > 1 row so you're more flexible when it comes to more advanced ramp-up and especially ramp-down behaviour. I.e. here is how you can add your load pattern one more time:

   [image]
2. On the other hand Concurrency Thread Group can be connected with the [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin/) via [Feedback Function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/#Use-With-Throughput-Shaping-Timer-Feedback-Function) so you will be able to control the throughput of your test execution and define it like: 100 requests per second and Concurrency Thread Group will add more threads if the current amount is not enough to reach/maintain the current throughput